# Laravel vapor fails when trying to run migrations for Postgres using pgsql-schema.dump

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vapor, vapor-cli

When doing a deploy using laravel vapor, I get the following error. I am using a pgsql-schema.dump for my migrations, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle it. I no longer have the original migrations to try as they got pruned when generating the dump. (See below)

### Many Thanks

Hook: migrate --force
Migration table created successfully.
Loading stored database schema: /var/task/database/schema/pgsql-schema.dump

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException

The command "pg_restore --no-owner --no-acl --clean --if-exists --host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}" --port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}" --username="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}" --dbname="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}"" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /var/task

## Output:

## Error Output:

sh: pg_restore: command not found

at vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:267
263▕      */
264▕     public function mustRun(callable $callback = null, array $env = []): static
265▕     {
266▕         if (0 !== $this->run($callback, $env)) {
➜ 267▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this);
268▕         }
269▕
270▕         return $this;
271▕     }

```
  +19 vendor frames
```

20  artisan:43
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Comment: Hope you committed before generating the dump. :) You should also be able to get the original migrations from an RDS back up but from git would be much easier.

Comment: Looks like for some reason the app can't find your dependencies or path variables? There are some issues about this in their GitHub, but I'd think the migrations got wiped with the --clean argument, and since it failed it never was able to recreate them?

Comment: I have committed, and can retrieve the migrations if necessary, but to me this seems like an issue with Vapor, if it can't handle a dump file, which is much neater than having to keep around a load of old migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross the same issue on mysql database. The error occured because I didn't have installed mysql-client, so I guess the same goes for you, just for the pgsql.
I am running vapor with docker runtime, so in my coresponding {environment}.Dockerfile I just added the following line `RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client`.
For you it would probably be `RUN apk add --no-cache pdo_pgsql`.